# Orbit of the Earth - numerical methods leapfrog

Tags: python, physics, numerical-methods

edit:
I get these plots now from earths orbit. However, total energy looks not right. Should it not be oscillating between 0?

Thanks again!

[image: E(t)]

I am attempting this numerical methods homework exercise part b).
[Orbit of the Earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf4Gg.png)

My goal is to modify my code from part a) so it returns kinetic and potential energy of earths orbit but I get this error:

```
(8.12).py:31: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  z_vec[i+1,:]=z_vec[i,:] + h*f(z_half_step, t_vec[i])
```

My code for finding kinetic and potential energy of earths orbit is obviously wrong. My problem is that I don't know how to modify my code in a) to find potential and kinetic energy.

This is my code for a:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi


"""a"""


G = 6.6738*10**-11
M = 1.9891*10**30
h = 3600
y = 1.4710*10**11
vx = 3.0287*10**4

def LeapFrog(f, t_start, t_stop, z0, h):

    t_vec = np.arange(t_start, t_stop, h) 
    n = len(t_vec)
    d = len(z0)  
    z_vec = np.zeros((n, d))
    z_vec[0,:] = z0
    z_half_step=z_vec[0 , :] + (1/2)*h*f(z0,t_vec[0]) 
    
    
    for i in range(0, n - 1):
        z_vec[i+1,:]=z_vec[i,:] + h*f(z_half_step, t_vec[i])
        z_half_step += h*f(z_vec[i+1,:], t_vec[i])   


    return t_vec, z_vec, 


def f(z,t):   #dz/dt
    
    x=z[0]
    y=z[1] 
    vx=z[2] 
    vy=z[3] 
    r=np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

    dz=np.zeros(4)
    
    dz[0]=vx 
    dz[1]=vy
    dz[2]=-G*M*x/r**3
    dz[3]=-G*M*y/r**3

    return dz

t_start = 0
t_stop = 24*365*h*5 #5 years
z0 = np.array([0,y,vx,0])
t_vec, z_vec = LeapFrog(f, t_start, t_stop, z0, h)



figure, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.title("Orbit of the Earth")
plt.plot(0,0,'yo', label = 'Sun positon')  
plt.plot(z_vec[:,0],z_vec[:,1], 'g', markersize=1, label='Earth trajectory')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

ax.set(xlim=(-1.55*10**11, 1.55*10**11), ylim = (-1.55*10**11, 1.55*10**11))
a_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1.4710*10**11, fill=False,color='r')
ax.add_artist(a_circle)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

legend = plt.legend(['Sun position','Earths 5-year trajectory','Perfect circle'],loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.show()



"""

We can see that the trajectory of the earth for 5 years is very slightly non-circular.

"""
```

For part b) I modified "dz[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf4Gg.png)" and "dz[3]". Obviously it didn't work:

```
"""b"""

    m = 5.9722*10**24
    def f(z,t):   #dz/dt
    
        x=z[0]
        y=z[1] 
        vx=z[2] 
        vy=z[3] 
        r=np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
    
        dz=np.zeros(4)
    
        dz[0]=vx 
        dz[1]=vy
        dz[2]=-G*M*m/r
        dz[3]=0.5*m*y**2
    
        return dz
    
    t_start = 0
    t_stop = 24*365*h*5 #5 years
    z0 = np.array([0,y,vx,0])
    LeapFrog(f, t_start, t_stop, z0, h)
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to include the full error trackback. Also attempt to reduce the code to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The error isn't the problem. The problem is the construction of modifying the code. Also it's part b of the problem so I think all the code from a) is necessary in order to understand the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make the actual output and expected output more clear

Comment: Ok, I've edited the post, and I hope the actual output and expected output is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no integration in part b), you use the result from part a) to compute the energies at each point.

```python
    x,y,vx,vy = z_vec.T
    r = np.hypot(x,y)
    E_kin = 0.5*m*(vx**2+vy**2)
    E_pot = -G*M*m/r
    E = E_kin+E_pot
    plt.plot(t,E)
```

Comment: Excellent! Do you mean t=t_vec in plt.plot(t,E)?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if I change it, there should be uniform naming conventions. `t_arr` would be better than `t_vec`, then also `vx_arr` etc.

Comment: The algorithm for the axis is so that the digits on the left side are the next digit relative to the basis point. So if the range were between x.y4 and x.y7, then the left axis would have digits from 4 to 7 and on top the basis point x.y and the scale factor for the next digit are given.

Comment: So you mean the y-axis is dependent on the x-axis? I thought the y-axis represented energy? Hence total energy should oscillate between 0? Is there any way to change the y-axis ? Thanks !

Comment: No worries. I think it might be fine with these plots. They show that total energy is constant in one plot, and conserved in longer periods in the other plot.

Comment: Sorry, should have used a.b for the digits before and after the decimal dot.